# converge absolutely of $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence

> I need to find  $x$ so that $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$ is absolute convergence

$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}$ is converge absolutely if :

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }|\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}|$$ is convergence

so  $$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }|\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}|=\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^2+n}$$

I can see that if $x>|n|$,  $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }|\frac{(-1)^n}{x^2+n}|$ is convergence

but how can I prove that ?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

No it is wrong, your number $x$ is fixed when you study its dependence on $n$.
If $x>n$ ? What is the value of $n$ ? It will takes all values of $n \in \mathbb{N}^{*}$ !

In fact your series have positives terms and
$$
\frac{1}{x^2+n}\underset{(+\infty)}{\sim}\frac{1}{n}
$$
Hence your series never converges absolutely as $\displaystyle \sum_{ n \geq 1}^{ }\frac{1}{n}$ diverges.

Comment: that is correct I can't take all values of n , what a stupid thing I did ! . thank you

Comment: Formally, would we use partial fractions to show that $\frac 1 {x^2 + n} = \frac 1 n + \dots$?

Comment: I dont understand the question :/ could you explain ?

Comment: While true that $\frac 1 {x^2 + n}$ approaches $\frac 1 n$, I believe the formal way to show this without handwaving is to express $\frac 1 {x^2+n}$ as a sum of two or more terms. One of those terms would be $\frac 1 n$, and the others would converge. It follows that the sum of all of them diverges.

Comment: The series have positive terms. It is equivalent to a divergent series, by equivalence criteria they have the same behavior. Then, they both diverge. ^^

Comment: Perhaps there's some theory I'm unfamiliar with. I'm not an expert in sequences. But here's my thinking: to show that two sequences are equivalent in the limit, wouldn't we have to show that the of "difference" between the two sequences converges? i.e. $\sum_n (\frac 1 n - \frac 1 {x^2-n}) $ converges ? How would you show that this sum is finite without circular logic?

Comment: You can use majoration criteria which is easy to prove : if $u_n \leq v_n$ ( with $u_n$ being positive ) and $\sum_{n \geq 0}^{ }v_n$ converges, then $\sum_{n \geq 0}^{ }u_n$  converges. Then, you can deduce the same for $u_n=o\left(v_n\right)$ and $u_n \sim v_n$ which are "hidden" majorations.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. I'm unable to find anything called the "majoration criterion". Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: I will delete this comment after but how can i send you a message ? I never found how lol

Answer (score 0):

To solve your question formally (without hand-waving), we might approach it this way:

We look at the behaviour of the sequence of terms like $a_n$ and note than in the limit of $n \rightarrow \infty$, it approaches a sequence which we know to diverge $(1/n)$. We then try to reexpress the sequence $a_n$:
$$a_n = A_n + \frac 1 n$$
because if we have a series of two terms
$$\sum_n a_n + b_n.$$
and we show that $\sum_n b_n$ converges, then the full series converges if and only if $\sum_n a_n$ converges.

---

It turns out that your sequence can be reexpressed as follows (I obtained this from taylor expansion about $x=0$ and summing all but the first term as a geometric series):

$$\frac 1 {x^2 + n} = \frac 1 n - \frac {x^2}{n(n+x^2)}$$
We know that $\left| \frac {x^2}{n(n+x^2)}\right| \leq x^2 \left| \frac {1}{n^2}\right|$ and so this portion of the sequence converges. It follows that your series converges iff $\sum_n 1/n$ converges. Which, of course, it does not.